# In TFS API, how do I get the full class name for a given test?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I have an [`ITestCaseResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestcaseresult.aspx) object in hand and I can't figure out how to extract the Test Class information from it. The object contains the test method's name in the `TestCaseTitle` property but there are a lot of duplicate titles across our code base and I would like more information.

Assuming I have `Foo.Bar` assembly with class `Baz` and method `ThisIsATestMethod`, I currently only have access to the `ThisIsATestMethod` information from the title, but I would like to obtain `Foo.Bar.Baz.ThisIsATestMethod`.

How can I do that using the TFS API?

Here's some stripped down code:

```
var def = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(teamProject.Name);
def.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 1;
def.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;
def.DefinitionSpec.Name = buildDefinition.Name;
def.Status = BuildStatus.Failed | BuildStatus.PartiallySucceeded | BuildStatus.Succeeded;

var build = buildServer.QueryBuilds(def).Builds.SingleOrDefault();
if (build == null)
    return;

var testRun = tms.GetTeamProject(teamProject.Name).TestRuns.ByBuild(build.Uri).SingleOrDefault();
if (testRun == null)
    return;

foreach (var outcome in new[] { TestOutcome.Error, TestOutcome.Failed, TestOutcome.Inconclusive, TestOutcome.Timeout, TestOutcome.Warning })
    ProcessTestResults(bd, testRun, outcome);
```

...

```
private void ProcessTestResults(ADBM.BuildDefinition bd, ITestRun testRun, TestOutcome outcome)
{
    var results = testRun.QueryResultsByOutcome(outcome);
    if (results.Count == 0)
        return;


    var testResults = from r in results // The "r" in here is an ITestCaseResult. r.GetTestCase() is always null.
                      select new ADBM.Test() { Title = r.TestCaseTitle, Outcome = outcome.ToString(), ErrorMessage = r.ErrorMessage };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by downloading the TRX file from TFS and parsing it manually.  To download the TRX file for a test run, do this:

```
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://my-tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
    ITestManagementService tms = tpc.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
    ITestManagementTeamProject tmtp = tms.GetTeamProject("My Project");
    ITestRunHelper testRunHelper = tmtp.TestRuns;
    IEnumerable<ITestRun> testRuns = testRunHelper.ByBuild(new Uri("vstfs:///Build/Build/123456"));
    var failedRuns = testRuns.Where(run => run.QueryResultsByOutcome(TestOutcome.Failed).Any()).ToList();
    failedRuns.First().Attachments[0].DownloadToFile(@"D:\temp\myfile.trx");
```

Then parse the TRX file (which is XML), looking for the <TestMethod> element, which contains the fully-qualified class name in the "className" attribute:

```
<TestMethod codeBase="C:/Builds/My.Test.AssemblyName.DLL" adapterTypeName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" className="My.Test.ClassName, My.Test.AssemblyName, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Test_Method" />
```

Comment: Wonderful, this works very well for my tool. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a way to get the Assembly name:

```
    foreach (ITestCaseResult testCaseResult in failures)
    {
        string testName = testCaseResult.TestCaseTitle;
        ITmiTestImplementation testImplementation = testCaseResult.Implementation as                 ITmiTestImplementation;
    string assembly = testImplementation.Storage;
    }
```

Unfortunately, **ITestCaseResult** and **ITmiTestImplementation** don’t seem to contain the namespace of the test case.

Check the last response in [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48effc10-4b42-4f70-825d-dbaa6d1bb06b/using-the-tfs-apis-to-find-the-name-assembly-and-namespace-of-a-failed-unit-test-after-a-build?forum=tfsbuild), that might help.
Good Luck!

**EDIT**: 
This is based on **Charles Crain**'s answer, but getting the class name without having to download to file:

```
    var className = GetTestClassName(testResult.Attachments);
```

And the method itself:

```
    private static string GetTestClassName(IAttachmentCollection attachmentCol)
    {
        if (attachmentCol == null || attachmentCol.Count == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var attachment = attachmentCol.First(att => att.AttachmentType == "TmiTestResultDetail");

        var content = new byte[attachment.Length];
        attachment.DownloadToArray(content, 0);
        var strContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content);

        var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(RemoveTroublesomeCharacters(strContent)));
        var root = XElement.Load(reader);
        var nameTable = reader.NameTable;
        if (nameTable != null)
        {
            var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
            namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010");

            var classNameAtt = root.XPathSelectElement("./ns:TestDefinitions/ns:UnitTest[1]/ns:TestMethod[1]", namespaceManager).Attribute("className");

            if (classNameAtt != null) return classNameAtt.Value.Split(',')[1].Trim();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    internal static string RemoveTroublesomeCharacters(string inString)
    {
        if (inString == null) return null;

        var newString = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var ch in inString)
        {
            // remove any characters outside the valid UTF-8 range as well as all control characters
            // except tabs and new lines
            if ((ch < 0x00FD && ch > 0x001F) || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
            {
                newString.Append(ch);
            }
        }
        return newString.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the application isn't running on the same machine as the tests so it doesn't have direct access to the assemblies...

Answer (score 2):

Since the details of the testcase are stored in the work item you can fetch the data by accessing the work item for the test case

```
ITestCaseResult result;
var testCase = result.GetTestCase();
testCase.WorkItem["Automated Test Name"]; // fqdn of method
testCase.WorkItem["Automated Test Storage"]; // dll
```

Comment: This looks promising, but `result.GetTestCase()` always returns null. Any idea of a which setting in my build definitions or in TFS could cause this?

Comment: I tried out something similar... 
var testRun = tcm.GetTeamProject("project").Find(1234); 
var tests = QueryResultsByOutcome(Passed); // ITestCaseResultCollection now you can get the testcaseIds from the list
testRun.TestCases.Find(tests[0].TestCaseId).WorkItem["Automated Test Name"] // gets me the name

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. `TestCaseId` is always `0`... I'll accept this answer anyway as it is the right one, I simply have another problem. I'll ask a new question instead. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One more way to verify this is to query all your test cases using WIT queries in TFS and verifying that the testcase ids that you are expecting are present in the system and then check the automated test case data. This will atleast help you verify that the artifacts we are trying to query actually exist or not :)

Comment: `tms.GetTeamProject("the project's name").TestResults.Query("SELECT * FROM TestResult Where TestCaseId <> 0")` returns 0 items...

Comment: So this is what TestManagement is telling you. Verify if WIT tells you the same. If it does then it means no data exists. If WIT tells you something different it means the TM api is not being consumed correctly... In WIT create a query Project=@Project & Work Item Type = Test Case && Test Case ID <> 0

Comment: Hmm actually, `Project=@Project & Work Item Type = Test Case` returns nothing, so it seems like there are no work items created at all. Where would that be configured in TFS? Thanks for your time by the way, really appreciated.

Comment: You create a test case as a part of a suite and associate automation details with it, without which it is considered a manual test case. This is stored in WIT at the project level. Based on above data these were not created at all. See this link on how to create them using tcm.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465191(v=vs.100).aspx. Hope you can get unblocked with this..

Answer (score 1):

```
public string GetFullyQualifiedName()
{
  var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection("http://tfstest:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
  var service = collection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();

  var tmProject = service.GetTeamProject(project.TeamProjectName);
  var testRuns = tmProject.TestRuns.Query("select * From TestRun").OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCompleted);

  var run = testRuns.First();

  var client = collection.GetClient<TestResultsHttpClient>();
  var Tests = client.GetTestResultsAsync(run.ProjectName, run.Id).Result;

  var FullyQualifiedName = Tests.First().AutomatedTestName;
  return FullyQualifiedName;
}
```

Comment: Checkout this repository:
https://github.com/sparkskapil/AzureUtilties